# Google Compute Engine VM Display Driver

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have created a google compute engine (GCE) VM, and regardless of the OS selected (Windows Server 2012, 2016, etc.) there is no virtual display driver that is installed.

I don't know if this is by design, or a consequence of the hyper-visor they are using, but some applications seem to require a display driver to bind to in order to load or connect. One example is Teamviewer, VNC, or Chrome Remote Desktop for remote access. It just displays a blank screen on the client side.

I'm wondering if anyone else has had this issue, and whether there is a driver that can be installed by the user to resolve this.

Comment: Accoring to the link here [Quickstart Using a Windows VM ](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/quickstart-windows) you should be able to connect using RDP.

Comment: [GPU features](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2016/11/announcing-GPUs-for-Google-Cloud-Platform.html) are in the road map for 2017.  Ideally you would access your VM via RDP but if you need to install a non-native access some options like Radmin and LogmeIn are mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703066/remote-control-via-team-viewer-on-a-google-compute-vm-instace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just and update, [GPU features](https://cloud.google.com/gpu/) are already available in beta.